# How many features does the RandomForest algorithm select?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-extraction

I'm working with random forest and I'd like to know how does the feature selection works.
I have a set of 423 features and I understand that they are randomnly selected using  log2(F)+ 1. So this way I get a 12/13 features subset.  But what I cannot understand is how random is the selection and if those subsets are supposed to be different for each tree or if the subset is the same for all the trees but what differ are the multiple combinations. 
If I have a model with 10 trees, is the feature selection supposed to vary from tree to tree? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should check this thesis: http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~glouppe/pdf/phd-thesis.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Each tree in the forest gets a different random sample of features. Decision tree learning is usually deterministic so if each tree had the same set of features, they would all learn the same decision tree, which defeats the purpose. You want them all to be trained on *different* subsets of features.

If the algorithm is selecting a subset of 12 features from the original set of 423 features, then each tree will get its own sample (without replacement) of 12 features from the full set.